# Select a Random Google Maps Pin

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

i'm working on Web Application that uses Google maps, this appication will insert a pin on the map at a random position, i need to click this pin to proceed with the process, but when i'm trying to set the object properties the pin still cannot be found.

I've tried to use OR and Descriptive programming but none has worked

```
Browser("System").Page("Planning").Image("src:=/Images/marker- 
blue.png").RightClick

Set descImage = Description.Create
descImage("html tag").value = "IMG"
descImage("image type").value = "Plain Image"
descImage("src").value = "Images/marker-blue\.png"
```

There's only one blue pin in the map.
The others pins are close to the blue, but they are all black and purple pins.

[image: Image from the map]

I'm new at UFT/QTP so o don't know to much about identifying objects

I'm Using UFT v14.00 
Google Chrome 64bits v67.0.3396.87

Comment: When you spy on the pin, what properties do you see?

Comment: can you spy on the pin using ObjectSpy and paste the properties so we can help?

Comment: This is the properties available

Comment: I've tried to use src=""/Images/marker-blue\.png propertie, but when i tried to run the UFT identifies more 4 objects with the same propertie

Comment: "Class Name:=Image", "abs_x:=772", "abs_y:=462", "file name:=marker-blue\.png", "height:=50", "html tag:=IMG", "image type:=Plain Image", "outerhtml:=<img alt="""" src=""/Images/marker-blue\.png"" draggable=""false"" style=""position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; user-select: none; width: 34px; height: 50px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none; opacity: 1;"" class="""">", "src:=mycompanyaddress/Images/marker-blue\.png", "visible:=True", "width:=34", "x:=772", "xpath:=//DIV[3]/DIV[2]/DIV[3]/DIV[1]/IMG[1]", "y:=325"

Comment: have you tried using ordinal identifier ?

Comment: tried by index, but appears 4 blue markers in the pag that are hidden, all of them have the same index

Comment: I can see in the above comments about properties - try using xpath or Visual relation ship identifier? Also have you tried getting the count of the Object (descImage) you created above ? at least that would narrow down your possible solution

Comment: I dont know how to count the objects